# Show that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $(X, d)$ is Cauchy iff for $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_{k}, x_{k+p})<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Show that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $(X, d)$ is Cauchy if and only if $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_{k}, x_{k+p})<\varepsilon$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

"$\Longrightarrow$" Assume that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Now we have that $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n, x_m) < \varepsilon$ whenever $n,m \ge k$. Now let $n = k$ so we have $d(x_k, x_m) < \varepsilon.$ But now since every point of the sequence $x_k$ after $k$ lies in our "good region" we have that $d(x_k, x_{k+p}) < \varepsilon$.

This would seem to work for "$\Longrightarrow$" although a bit informal. How can I approach "$\Longleftarrow$"? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: If $j <k$ then  $k=j+p$ for some $p \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $(x_n)$ fulfills the condition. Then it holds that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $k\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$ d(x_k,x_{k+p})<\frac\varepsilon 2\quad\forall p\in\mathbb N.$$
Now for $m,n\geq k$ it holds that $m=k+p_1$ and $n=k+p_2$ with $p_1,p_2\in\mathbb N$. Applying the triangle inequality yields
$$d(x_m,x_n)\leq d(x_m,x_k)+d(x_n,x_k)=d(x_{k+p_1},x_k)+d(x_{k+p_2},x_k)<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: This is for "$\Longrightarrow$" not "$\Longleftarrow$" since I've already assumed that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy?

Comment: @Simeon he has shown that your condition implies Cauchy. The reverse implication is (also) trivial.